# How to clear android cached .apk data

Tags: apk, cache

I'm developing a mobile application for android and testing with a physical device. I have two versions quite different but same name etc. When I deinstall one apk to test the other, the old one is reinstalled. So my question is, how do I clear this cached data ? and why android keeps in memory an application when a user asks for it to be removed ...

Comment: How do you install the APK files? from within Android Studio or via ADB?

Comment: I install them from file system, I have the apks in a folder on my device

Comment: By "same name", I assume "same package name"? Since app's name doesn't really affect other apps. Otherwise, do both apps sharing the same external data location? Anyway, check if the global backup settings is active on Android's Settings, because some phones automatically restore app's data on reinstall. (I've experienced it while developing an app, reference: [Back up or restore data on your Android device](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819582)

Comment: Yes by name I mean package name, and they usually share the same location, but even if i delete the old .apk file, some data must be stored somewhere.
and the back up is disabled